# org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: output\getOrders.txt

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am learning Camel Integration with Springboot. I was trying to get the json response from restapi and then want to store the data into some file.

Below is the route class component which I created . It is not able to convert the json response into filestream type. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

```
      rest().get("/orders").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route().
      setBody(()-> orderService.getOrders()).to("direct:transferToFile").endRest();

      from("direct:transferToFile").convertBodyTo(Order.class).to("file:output?fileName=getOrders.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write an Order object into a file. You need to marshal it into json before writing it to the file.

You can add a `marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` after the `convertBodyTo`.

Comment: Sneha, now I am able to write the response to file, but when I hit the url for /orders now there I am getting some encrypted data , something like below

"eyJpZCI6MTIsIm5hbWUiOiJNb2JpbGUiLCJwcmljZSI6MTAwMDAuMH0="

So do I need to create separate endpoints for getting the orders and then again for transferring it to some file

Comment: Did you set a bindingmode in the restconfiguration? The data you are getting is a base64 version of the json body. This happens when you set the bindingmode as Json, and then try to marshal it again.

Comment: yes I have set it like this----
 restConfiguration().component("servlet").port(9090).host("localhost")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

  rest().get("/orders").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route().
    setBody(()-> orderService.getOrders()).to("direct:transferToFile").endRest();
    
    
    //Saving a rest response into text file
    from("direct:transferToFile").convertBodyTo(Order.class).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
  .to("file:output?fileName=getOrders.txt");

Comment: Can you remove the `bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)` option and try again? Since you are manually marshalling the object into json, you wouldn't need the binding mode.

Comment: This is working but if I am using other http methods also like post or put and there I won't want to save the data in a file then I will have to set the bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json). Can you tell me then how will I do that ?

Comment: You can add the bindingmode to individual http verbs instead of doing that globally in the restconfiguration. For example, you can do `get("/api"). bindingmode (RestBindingMode.json).//rest of your route`

Comment: If you know about weblogic jms and camel in spring boot , can you tell me as i am getting an error. I have posted a separete question for this with all the details

Comment: Sneha, I tried with following code but when I hit the url there is empty set in the output. DO you have any idea why it is not able to get the data? 
rest().get("/getproducts").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route()

.setBody(() -> service.getProducts()).to("http:/localhost:8090/getProducts").process(new JsontoTxtProcessor())

.to("file:/C:/input").endRest();

Comment: You can do a system.out.println of the message body in the JsontoTxtProcessor, and check if there is anything present at all. It is not possible to tell more without looking at the complete code. If possible, you can create a github repo, and I can give a look at the code.